# What are the rules, laws, and procedures to approve and remove press members from white house press conferences?

Tags: united-states, president, constitution, media, first-amendment

In November 2018, an event in American politics involved a certain reporter for CNN, Jim Acosta, having his press credentials revoked by the White House, thereby barring his access to the White House press conferences. My immediate and admittedly ignorant impression is that the president has no duty to hold press conferences and can  therefore allow or disallow any party's attendance.

CNN and many other news organizations apparently see it differently, resulting in a lawsuit naming the president himself, among others, for both 1st amendment and 5th amendment violations. To my surprise, [a judge agreed and ordered the White House to immediately reinstate Jim Acosta's press credentials](https://cnn.com/cnn/2018/11/16/media/cnn-trump-lawsuit-hearing/index.html).

The lawsuit also charged that there is a procedure for removing press representatives, and that this procedure was not followed. With my understanding being that the president has no duty to hold press conferences in the first place, to what extent does the White House have a duty to follow a procedure when admitting or barring specific press representatives to White House press conferences? Are there rules, laws, or just precedents based on previous presidential actions?  To extend further to the president personally, to what extent is the president's duty to entertain any press person at any specific time or place?

Comment: I thought the press tag would be appropriate, but it seems it doesn't exist. I am a little surprised.

Comment: The President having or not the obligation to hold press conferences has nothing to do with the Press having access or not to the White house.

Comment: https://www.cnn.com/2018/11/16/media/cnn-trump-lawsuit-hearing/index.html

Comment: This is something that cannot be answered at this point.  There are so many forces: the separations of powers of the 3 branches of government, rules that are not a laws but come from non-elected officials, the addition of social/political pressures (i.e. is it the letter of the law or the spirit?).  Each of these forces have a judicial precedent of going either way often arbitrary or feelings based.  This will go to the supremes before we have an answer

Comment: @Chaim That article gives the impression that there are currently *no rules*. Is that also what you get from it?

Comment: @fredsbend We have a `media` tag. The tag description doesn't quite match, but I think it would be a good fit for the question.

Comment: @max I don't think that's correct.  Looking at [Sherrill v. Knight](https://openjurist.org/569/f2d/124/sherrill-v-h-knight), "White House press facilities having been made publicly available as a source of information for newsmen...requires that this access not be denied arbitrarily or for less than compelling reasons." (paragraph 13).  So, the White House or the President could stop giving press briefings, but so long as they are they must have a non-arbitrary procedure for allowing and disallowing access (or at least, that question is unresolved and it's likely to always be moot).

Comment: @fredsbend I was actually just offering an updated link to replace the one in the question. But yes, I agree that that the article gives the impression that there are no rules. This seems to me a probably false impression; common sense seems to dictate the existence of some rules.

Comment: @fredsbend One Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House_Press_Secretary) contains the following references to rules:  press conference rules mandated that reporters could attribute quotes or statements only to a "White House spokesman" and not directly to the President himself… Tumulty also worked to clarify embargo rules for the press, ordering that the exact time a press embargo was lifted be noted on the confidential information that was being released… [Stephen] Early also came under fire for the rules surrounding African American journalists not... allowed to attend...

Comment: [A related op-ed at the NYP](https://nypost.com/2018/11/17/jim-acosta-abused-his-privileges-as-a-member-of-the-press/)

Comment: [The white house has made some explicit rules for conduct during press conferences](https://thehill.com/homenews/media/417661-chuck-todd-rips-absurd-white-house-rules-no-serious-journalist-will-follow). It says plainly these rules were simply polite manners in the past, but the incident with Acosta has made this written version necessary.